# Microsserviços e Clusters

Tags: docker, microsserviços, microsoft-azure

Bom dia. Tenho uma dúvida a respeito de clusters e microserviços.

Qual é maneira correta de fazer o deploy de microserviço, um por cluster? Ou pode ser mais?

Irei exemplificar:

Tenho um app que é formado por 10 microsserviços. Cada microsserviço tem 2 containers, 1 para o "esqueleto" mvc outro para o banco de dados.

Então ao todo uso 20 containers (sem escalonar).

```
api-cadastro-de-pessoa -> 2 containers
api-cadastro-de-produtos -> 2 containers
api-carrinho-de-compra -> 2 containers
e assim vai.
```

O correto seria eu fazer o deploy de uma api por cluster? Estou aprendendo no Azure com kubernetes.
Valeu a atenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe uma forma certa de se fazer, claro que pode existir a formar mais coerente pra você. Cada caso é um caso, se eu estivesse com o mesmo problema que você eu usuária apenas 1 cluster dependendo da demanda,tudo depende da configuração da sua máquina e do número de requisição para a sua aplicação.

Se você estiver usando node abaixo de 200k/req eu acho que ele vai ficar de boa, apesar de usar 1 thread.

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde, na verdade você pode ter dezenas de microserviços em único cluster. O cluster é o conjunto de apis que formam o produto Kubernetes que tem como recurso mais conhecido a gerência da escalabilidade horizontal e ou vertical de acordo com a necessidade de recursos do microserviço.

Em linhas gerais uma boa prática é ter um container para cada pod. E melhor ainda, é  concentrar um pod em cada node. Esse tipo de arquitetura facilita o debug, traz métricas de monitoramento mais eficientes, e dá possibilidade de escalar recursos para o microserviço com base exatamente no que ele precisa, pois não há concorrência de containers no mesmo pod, e ou concorrência de pods no mesmo node.

Exemplo:

1 node -> 1 pod -> 1 container.